# OnLocationStateChange cordova application crashes

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

The application i am working is basically fetches users location using cordova geolocation plugin, and then show the location on the google maps.

The problem i'm facing is that when i kill the app and turn off/on the location services from settings the application crashes.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$LocationProviderChangedReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void cordova.plugins.Diagnostic.notifyLocationStateChange()' on a null object reference
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void cordova.plugins.Diagnostic.notifyLocationStateChange()' on a null object reference

[image]
this is the screen shot of error that i got after running the app directly from Android studio

I'm using diagnostic plugin as well because i'm testing app on API 23 i-e Marshmallow, that needs run time permissions. if i remove diagnostic plugin the app crashes as soon as it starts on Marshmallow.

The app runs on API's below 23 and also it does not crashes when i turn location services On/Off.

Advices/Suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is noted as [issue #85](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/85) in the [plugin repo](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) and is resolved by patch release `cordova.plugins.diagnostic@3.0.4`:

```
$ cordova plugin rm cordova.plugins.diagnostic && 
  cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic@latest
```

Comment: thanks for answering i will test this and let you know the results . 
BTW i also solve the problem by putting this instance = new Diagnostic();
just before this instance.notifyLocationStateChange();

Comment: I just re-read your question - so your crash occurs when the app is **not** running which I think is a different issue from the one fixed in #80, which occurred when the app is running. I will look into it...

Comment: Yes exactly when i kill the app and turn on/off location service app crashes.

Comment: I've added this as a new [issue #85](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/85)

Comment: I guess soon the bug will be fixed

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Comment: Thankyou for the help. :)