# Cordova app closes unexpectedly

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, crash

I developed a hybrid app using cordova. I uploaded it to google play and app store. Users reported that they are getting a message "Unfortunately, xxx has closed" (xxx represents the app name). While testing I am not able to reproduce the issue. The strange part is users get this message when they are not using my app. I had the following plugins installed in my app

```
cordova-plugin-camera 2.2.1-dev "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.1.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.0 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.1.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.4.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.0 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.4-dev "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.3.2 "Toast"
cordova-sqlite-storage 0.7.14 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.0.2 "Diagnostic"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.0 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 5.0.0 "BarcodeScanner"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.6.4 "PushPlugin"
```

Ios users are not getting this crash message. Only android users reported this issue.

Here is my Androidmanifest.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.xxx.yy" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$LocationProviderChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="Share" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="Share" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.HelpActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.BackgroundActionButtonHandler" />
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.GCMIntentService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.RegistrationIntentService" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

I had two functions in my code, which invoke automatically. Both are used to sync the data to server.

```
$interval(function() {
        var isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
        if (isOnline) {
            $scope.syncData();
        }
    }, 900000)
```

and

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState) {
        if ($scope.isLoggedIn) {
            var onlineState = networkState;
            console.log('Online State', onlineState);
            $scope.syncData();
        }

    });
```

Will this functions call in background ? Will this functions persist after app close ?
I couldn't find anything unusual during debug. 
Can anyone help me ?

**Update**

I found two scenarios this occurred:

1. I was changing the network state to flight mode due to network
   issue. Suddenly I got the message that Unfortunately xxx has stopped
2. My GPS was disabled. I was trying to open google maps. I got a
   message from google map to enable GPS. At the time I enabled GPS, I
   got message that Unfortunately xxx has stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37760900/777265), this is caused by a bug in `cordova.plugins.diagnostic@3.0.2`, noted as [issue #85](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/85) in the [plugin repo](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) and is resolved by patch release `cordova.plugins.diagnostic@3.0.4`. Updating the plugin and rebuilding your app should resolve the issue:

```
$ cordova plugin rm cordova.plugins.diagnostic && 
  cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic@3.0.4 &&
  cordova build android --release
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I didn't noticed about this issue. Infact, I was not aware of which plugin causes this error. I found two different scenarios when this issue occured. I upadted my question also. I am using the diagnostic plugin to check the GPS permission status. So that might be the problem of second scenario. But what  will be the reason for second scenario  ? Any idea ?

Comment: Both scenarios are caused by the above mentioned bug and will be fixed by updating the plugin

Comment: Ok thank you. I just updated the plugin. Let me try some random test cases. Appreciate your response and pointing this out